# How i take a value that is like field in my database?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I try to get values that contains words in my sql database. I try with "contains" but I get an error. I work with SQL

This is my code:

```
router.post('/busca',isLoggedIn, async (req,res) => {
            const {busca} = req.body;
            const buscar = Object.values({busca});
            const bus = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM links WHERE title CONTAINS ?',[buscar]);
            res.render('links/busca',{buscar, bus});

        });
```

I have this error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(title, 'a')' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LIKE operator :

```
SELECT * FROM links WHERE title LIKE '%word%';
```

if you are more than one word use `and` or `or` operator

```
SELECT * FROM links WHERE title LIKE '%word%' AND title LIKE '%secondword%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Contains doesn't exist in mysql .
use LIKE

```
const bus = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM links WHERE title LIKE ?',[%buscar%]);
```